# Helm pass single string to a template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

there are multiple stackoverflow answers regarding passing multiple variables to a template in Helm, using dictionary.

However, I want to pass a single variable to a template. For example, I want to define template such as below, receiving input (a string to be exact).

```
{{- define "blahblah" $var }}
  {{- if .Values.nameOverride }}
  name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}-$var
  {{- else }}
  name: $var
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Thus, writing like below, I expect the result to be `name: myname-whatever` or `name:whatever` (assuming `.Values.nameOverride` was defined as 'myname')

```
{{- include "blahblah" "whatever" }}
```

How can I let helm know which is the input variable to the template? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Go `text/template` template only accepts one parameter, and its value inside the template is the special variable `.`.  So you could, for example:

```
{{- define "name" -}}
name: {{ . }}
{{ end -}}
{{- template "name" "foo" -}}
```

```yaml
name: foo
```

Or, you can pass in the Helm top-level object

```
{{- define "name-override" -}}
name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}
{{ end -}}
{{- template "name-override" . -}}
```

Notice in this case that, inside the `define`d template, we're referring to the `Values` field of `.`, and when we call it via `template`, we're explicitly passing down `.` as the parameter.  Again, though, you only get one parameter.

Here you need *two* parameters: the Helm root value plus the additional value you're trying to pass in.  I tend to use a [`list`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lists-and-list-functions) to package the two parameters together into one value:

```
{{- define "blahblah" -}}
{{- $top := index . 0 -}}
{{- $var := index . 1 -}}
{{- if $top.Values.nameOverride -}}
name: {{- $top.Values.nameOverride -}}-{{ $var }}
{{ else -}}
name: {{ $var }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}

{{ include "blahblah" (list . "whatever") | indent 2 }}
```

So the parameter to the template, when you call it, is a list; `index . 0` is the first item out of `.`, or the top-level Helm value, and `index . 1` is the second item.  The reverse of this is, since `.` is a list, you need to qualify values that actually are part of the top-level Helm value with the variable name `$top` that holds that value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70927158/cant-evaluate-field-values-in-type-string-when-using-helm-template

Comment: Opened up one more question! Thanks.

Comment: If these functions are written in a helper file, wouldn't they be able to directly access 
 .Values without having to pass them in the function as a param?

Comment: No, `.Values` is the `Values` field on the object `.`, which is the single function parameter here, and you need to explicitly pass the top-level Helm object down in `template` and `include` calls (no matter where they're defined).